# Plotting mean values of groups in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, plot, group-by, mean

I have conducted a study with triplicates (SampleID) for each sample (Sample) on different time points.
Now, I want to plot the means of the triplicates for the characteristic "Aerobic".
I want to plot for example the development of amount of aerobic bacteria over time. Therefore, I need to calculate the means (and the standard deviation) of the triplicates and then plot these means in the graph. Here, I could imagine to  use a geom_line or geom_point diagram.

```
  SampleID  Sample     Aerobic  Anaerobic Day
    [Factor] [Factor]    [num]     [num]   [num]
1    V1.1.K1  V1.1.K 0.610063430 0.05146154   1
2    V1.1.K2  V1.1.K 0.740887757 0.02115290   1
3    V1.1.K3  V1.1.K 0.683726217 0.04270182   1
4    V1.1.N1  V1.1.N 0.432019752 0.35722350   1
5    V1.1.N2  V1.1.N 0.515792694 0.41357935   1
6  V1.14.K16 V1.14.K 0.038141335 0.84496088  14
7  V1.14.K17 V1.14.K 0.042078682 0.76523093  14
8  V1.14.K18 V1.14.K 0.009594763 0.90767637  14
9   V1.14.N0 V1.14.N 0.513100502 0.10618731  14
10 V1.14.W16 V1.14.W 0.483710571 0.32765968  14
```

How should i do this?
I tried it with the following code

```
plot <- mydata %>%
        group_by(Sample) %>%
        mutate(Mean=mean(Aerobic)) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x=Day, y=Aerobic)) +
        geom_point()
```

If I google the questions I get only information about how to calculate the mean alone, but not to set up a new table with the means for the different variables.
Is there something like

```
calc_mean_by_group ??
```

You would help me a lot :)

Comment: Could you clarify a bit further? In your example, you have `mean(SampleID)` - did you want the mean of `Aerobic` for each sample, something like `mean(Aerobic)`? If you do that, after your `group_by` statement, it will calculate the mean `Aerobic` for each "Sample". Also, describe what you would like to see in your plot, the type (bars, lines), including axes (such as "Mean Aerobic" vs. "Sample").

Comment: Hey Ben, I edited my post. I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

Simple base-R solution for calculating the means:

```
tapply(X = foo$Aerobic, INDEX = foo$Sample, FUN = mean)
```

("foo" being the name of your data.frame)